# call javascript object method with a variable

Tags: javascript, object

i am new to object oriented javascript. I have a variable whose value i would like to use to call an object's method. like this..

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() {},
    barr: function() {}
}
```

now there is a variable whose value can be any of the two method's names `bar` and `barr`
i want to call them with something like

```
var myvar = 'bar';
foo.{myVar}();
```

Comment: If you are starting to learn JavaScript, this may be a nice article to read: John Resig's [Learning Advanced Javascript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/). I know it says "advanced", but it starts from basic examples, and has a nice interactive interface for modifying and running the code.

Comment: @Groo  hey! thanks alot! a am new to object stuff and TBH they are a bit confusing.. :O but i am on it :D

Answer (score 51, accepted):

So I assume you want to call the appropriate function dynamically based on a string. You can do something like this:

```
var myVar = 'bar';
foo[myVar]();
```

Or you can also use `eval` but this is riskier (prone to injection attack) and slower (**don't do this!** :P):

```
var myVar = 'bar';
eval('foo.' + myVar + '()');
```

Comment: thanks.. there are so many answers :O looks like i asked a n00b question :P but hey thanks every body :)

Comment: There is no n00b question except the one that was just answered :)

Comment: :D so apparently they work like arrays too.. we can call them like we call an array `array['key']`. interesting. thnx!

Comment: @Achshar - In your example, foo is an object.  All objects can access their properties with array-type syntax.  It isn't really an array (which is why I wrote this comment to make sure you don't think it's an array), but you can use the foo['x'] syntax to access the properties just the same as you can use foo.x.

Comment: @jfriend00 oh yeaa i know that right :) i was just wondering that the syntax is same so that devs don't have to remember a bunch of different syntaxes for all the different things in the language :D

Comment: If people shouldn't do something, don't put it in the answer!

Answer (score 11):

Since you can access elements of an object via subscript notation, the following will do what you're looking for:

```
var myVar = 'bar';
foo[myVar]();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can just say:

```
foo[myVar]();
```

Since `foo` is a JavaScript object, this code will reference the member by name contained in the `myVar` variable.

Answer (score 5):

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() { alert('bar'); },
    barr: function() { alert('barr'); }
}


var myvar = 'bar';
foo[myvar](); // alert 'bar'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use something like: `foo[myVar]();`

Comment: calling inside the object methods this way doesn't seem to work. using try/catch the message says 'this[myVar] is not a function'

Answer (score 4):

it should be something like this

```
foo[myvar]();
```