# dynamically call an object with sub objects

Tags: javascript, object

i am new to JS objects. I have such code

```
var foo = {
    bar0: {
        barr0: function() {//doo stuff}
        barr1: function() {//doo stuff}
    },
    bar1: {
        barr0: function() {//do stuff}
        barr1: function() {//do stuff}
    },
    bar2: function() {//do stuff}
}
```

now i have this variable `myVar` that holds the 'name' of any of the above in the format they would be called. like it can have `bar0.barr1` or `bar2` or mention to any other of the above objects. `foo` will not be a part of `myVar` because it is common for every call. One possible solution is to use `eval` but i would like to avoid it if possible.

if the object was one dimensional i would have used [`foo[myVar]()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737840/call-javascript-object-method-with-a-variable) but this is now multidimensional and i hav no idea how should i call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply some scripting then.

```
// define our access string and copy a reference from foo into level
var myVar = 'bar0.barr1',
    level = foo;

// split that access string into an Array (splitted by dots) and loop over it
myVar.split(/\./).forEach(function( prop ) {
    // if the property name ("bar0", "barr1") is available in our target object
    if( prop in level ) {
        // overwrite our level variable with the new object property reference, so somekind "climb up" the latter if we're dealing with nested objects
        level = level[ prop ];
    }
});

// if we're done, check if level holds a function reference and if so, execute it.
if( typeof level === 'function' ) {
    level();
}
```

Comment: can you please add some comments describing what the above code does? and should i wrap this into a function? since i will need to call it multiple times..

Comment: how will this work with the third dimension and beyond? from what i understand, it overrides the `level` var with each additional 'dimension' so in `bar0.barr0.barrr0` `level` will be `barr0['barrr0']` .. but it has to be `bar[barr0][barrr0]` right?

Comment: [Not all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156696/which-web-browsers-natively-support-array-foreach) know about forEach.

Comment: oh okiee.. never mind.. it replaced `level` with what `level` was before + new prop. Thanks a ton.. it works like a charm :D

Comment: @whitequark no worries.. it is for a chrome app which requires minimum version 13 ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference for multidimensional, just keep adding square brackets:

```
foo[myVar][myvar2]()
```

Edit: Never mind, misunderstood the question, which is ironic because I actually asked almost exactly this question!

[In javascript how can I dynamically get a nested property of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906108/in-javascript-how-can-i-dynamically-get-a-nested-property-of-an-object)

Comment: i cant.. myVar is only one variable that has *all* the levels of objects.