# Conditions in the sequence of commands

Tags: jquery

Trying to figure out a way to insert a condition in Jquery sequence of commands.
Basically my point is I can save the code length.

Example:

```
var first=true;

if(first){
    ap.nextAll("div").first()....
}else{
    ap.nextAll("div").last()....
}
```

and whether it can do something like this:

```
ap.nextAll("div").(first?first():last())....
```

This is the only example I know that it could be solve `: last`, but it just as an example.

Thanks Pesulap

Comment: I might describe enough, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [call javascript object method with a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737840/call-javascript-object-method-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use bracket notation along with ternary operator

```
ap.nextAll("div")[first? 'first' : 'last']()....
```

Comment: This blew my mind. I was about to post a contradictory answer.

Comment: 'first' and 'last' is function so it might be without quote?

Comment: No, `first` and `last` are properties of jQuery objects that name functions. When using brackets, you put them in quotes to get the properties.

Comment: @C-link no... we are using a bracket notation and is passing object keys which are referencing functions... so the keys are strings

Comment: @Arun P Johny - Nice, and it would function in the condition still concatenate? ex: [first? "first". "hide", "last". "show"] ()

Comment: @Pesulap no `ap.nextAll("div")[first? 'first' : 'last']()[first? 'hide' : 'show']()` may be?

Comment: @Arun P Johny - Ok, thanks a lot, I thought it was impossible. And I do not think this is a duplicate topic.