# Access objects by a combination of an object and two paths

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, object

I would like to combine an object, a path in a variable and a path, something like explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43849204/14480225 but with **3** "parts".

Here is minimal reproducible example:
I want the `combine()` function to print `selector[0].children[foo].textContent` or `selector[0].children[foo].children[0].textContent` depending on `bar` value.

```js
const selector = document.getElementsByClassName('main')
const foo = 0
let bar = ''

const toggle = () => {
  if (bar === '') bar = '.children[0]'
  else bar = ''
}

const test = () => {
  console.log(combine('selector[0].children[foo]', bar, '.textContent'))
  //I want a function like combine() that will print 'selector[0].children[foo].textContent' or 'selector[0].children[foo].children[0].textContent' depending on bar value.
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <h1>Hello<span>world</span></h1>
  <button onclick='toggle()'>toggle</button>
  <button onclick='test()'>test</button>
</div>
```

I have a class that is returning multiple similar properties (10). My constructor inputs a value that can be used to determine something like `bar` in the minimal example. Each property by just changing something like `bar` in the minimal example can have the intended output.
I want something like this to be able to switch between different cases without having to write a massive switch for each `bar` cases so a lot of code duplication.

Comment: @ikiK - Thats what the OP want you to write for them ;-); The OP is making us read a 12 page novel (the other question) so they can be concise and leave out details I guess. For instance, in code the Op passes `selector[0].children` while stating "in my own code I have" `selector.children` - so, is the OP using a different selector "in my code" - we don't know.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) . No description of a problem to solve other than gimmie code that does what I want. OP should define the problem rather than dictate how to write the solution.

Comment: Well i tried, i asked for end result, so i excepted to get if `x` then `?` if `y `then `?` .  Should be clear after that judged on HTML. But I didn't get that... @RandyCasburn

Comment: I get that and I appreciate you tried. But the problem isn't producing that string you can use as a way to get text from an element, let's say. It seems the problem statement might be something like this: Given selector and which child of the selector and which property name to retrieve, produce a function that takes those arguments and returns the property value. Something like that right?

Comment: @RandyCasburn yeah get that

Comment: @ikiK - sorry - thought I was responding to the OP. Hope the OP reads my comments.

Comment: I have a simple solution that matches my comment description if the OP is interested. But if this is some odd homework thing or contrived job application test, whatevs.

Comment: Edited my question, is what you asked?

Comment: Check out this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/rakecezeze/1/edit?js,output) - you'll see the function takes three arguments. The first is a selector for the element you want to choose, the second is what are calling `bar` but continually referring to as `child[something]`, so the second is the # of the child to choose, and the third is the property you desire. You'll see how it works in the sample. If my code works for you, let me know and I'll post as an answer.

Comment: @RandyCasburn `bar` is not continually referring to as `.children[something]`, as I say in the question, it can also be nothing (represented by an empty string in my example)

Comment: OK, that's easy enough - either nothing or a child at some depth - right?

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes

Comment: Updated [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/joxicahuku/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? But please read about `eval()`  here before using it:
[call javascript object method with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737840/call-javascript-object-method-with-a-variable)

```js
const selector = document.getElementsByClassName('main')
const foo = 0
let bar = ''

const toggle = () => {
  if (bar === '') bar = '.children[0]'
  else bar = ''
}

function combine(){
let result = "selector[0].children[foo]"+bar+".textContent"
return result
}

const test = () => {
  console.log(eval(combine()))
  //I want a function like combine() that will print 'selector[0].children[foo].textContent' or 'selector[0].children[foo].children[0].textContent' depending on bar value.
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <h1>Hello<span>world</span></h1>
  <button onclick='toggle()'>toggle</button>
  <button onclick='test()'>test</button>
</div>
```

And here is a safe way of using it:

```js
const selector = document.getElementsByClassName('main')
const foo = 0
let bar = ''

const toggle = () => {
  if (bar === '') bar = '.children[0]'
  else bar = ''
}

function combine(){
return Function('"use strict";return (selector[0].children[foo]'+bar+'.textContent)')()
}

const test = () => {
  console.log(combine())

}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <h1>Hello<span>world</span></h1>
  <button onclick='toggle()'>toggle</button>
  <button onclick='test()'>test</button>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval

Comment: Works, thanks! But I'm worried about security, how eval is dangerous, is eval dangerous in my context? I'm writting a Deno module fetching an open website.
And also your two links are identical.

Comment: @Weebonn Yeah i don't know about that, there is some talk about it yes, i was wondering how to do this and remembered i seen it somewhere, you should research more about it.

Comment: Saw in the MDN doc that eval can be replaced by something else, but I could not get this working. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!

Comment: @Weebonn thanks for the link! Fixed it, check new snippet

Comment: Works perfectly in a code snippet but not with deno-dom, I've submitted a new [issue](https://github.com/b-fuze/deno-dom/issues/34) on deno-dom. I'll pick this answer, safe and easy to use.

Comment: UPDATE: not a deno-dom issue, not a deno issue either, this works in Deno: `(new Function("selector", "foo", '"use strict";return (selector[0].children[foo]' + bar + '.textContent)'))(selector, foo)`, see [this](https://github.com/b-fuze/deno-dom/issues/34) to see why.

Comment: @Weebonn Interesting, Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is `querySelector` to find the element you are after.

Read about [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) so you could understand better.

Using `eval` is not recommended and it is risky.

See if you like my idea below.

```js
const selector = document.getElementsByClassName('main')
const path = ":nth-child(1)"

function getText(s, p) {
  if (s.length) // Is array
     return Array.from(s).map(x=> x.querySelector(p)?.textContent ?? "").join(" ");
  return  s.querySelector(p)?.textContent;
}

console.log(getText(selector, path))
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <h1>Hello<span>world</span></h1>
  <button onclick='toggle()'>toggle</button>
  <button onclick='test()'>test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed in the comments, here is a solution that takes tree arguments and dynamically retrieves the property from the element of your choosing. Optionally, if you include the depth as number of children, the prop will be retrieved from that child.

### Demonstration

#### Given:

The need to pass a CSS selector
The number of the child element or empty string
The property name for the value needed

#### When:

Passing those three given parmeters to a function

#### Then:

That function should return the value of the property identified from the child identified by number if provided of the element chosen with the selector.

### Click test to run

```js
// NOTE: No error checking - this is only a demonstration

function getValueFromDOM(selector, child, prop) {
  if (!child) {
    return document.querySelector(`${selector}`)[prop];
  } 
  return document.querySelector(`${selector}`).querySelector(`:nth-child(${child})`)[prop];
}

var children = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function test() {
  children.forEach(child => {
    const value = getValueFromDOM('.main', child, 'textContent');
    output.innerHTML += `<p>${value}</p>`;
  });
  // With empty second argument - will print 'main'
  output.innerHTML += getValueFromDOM('.main', '', 'className')

}

document.querySelector('button:last-of-type').addEventListener('click', test);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='main'>
    <h4>Hello<span>world</span></h4>
    <button>toggle</button>
    <button>test</button>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div>Five</div>
    <div>Six</div>
  </div>
  <h3>Output:</h3>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```